# Comparing a string value to the input from the user isn't being evaluated properly

Tags: javascript, command-line

```
// Computer randomly selects Rock, Paper / Scissors
        computerChoice = function computerPlay() {
            let r = Math.random() * 3;
            let choice;

            if(r > 2) {
                console.log('Rock');
                return 'rock';
            } else if (r > 1) {
                console.log('Scissors');
                return 'scissors';
            } else {
                console.log('Paper');
                return 'paper';
            }
        }


        //compare results
        function compareChoice(userChoice, computerChoice) {
            if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
            console.log('Draw')
            } else if(userChoice === 'paper') {
                if(computerChoice == 'scissors') {
                    console.log ('You lose, try again!')
                } else {
                    console.log('You win!')
                }
            } else if(userChoice === 'rock') {
                if(computerChoice === 'paper') {
                    console.log('You lose! Try again!')
                } else {
                    console.log('You win!')
                }
            } else if(userChoice === 'scissors') {
                if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
                    console.log('You Lose! Try again!')
                } else {
                    console.log('You win!')
                }
            }

        }



        function game() {
            let userChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors!');
            console.log('Your choice was ' + userChoice);
            computerChoice();
            compareChoice();
        }

        game();
```

Hello! I'm trying to complete a simple Rock, paper scissors project for the Odin project in Javascript, however whenever I try to compare the string value to the input from the user it keeps logging draw, which would mean that it's being evaluated as true for the first if statement, irrespective of what the user enters. I've searched and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be sincerely appreciated thanks!

Comment: Your `compareChoice()` function is written such that it requires two parameters, but you call it with none.

Comment: Also you call `computerChoice()` but the code ignores the value it returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `compareChoice()` function, the code doesn't know the values for `userchoice` and `computerChoice()`. Change your code to pass these values as arguments to `compareChoice()` as follows:

```js
computerChoice = function computerPlay() {
    let r = Math.random() * 3;
    let choice;

    if (r > 2) {
         console.log('Rock');
         return 'rock';
    } else if (r > 1) {
        console.log('Scissors');
        return 'scissors';
    } else {
        console.log('Paper');
        return 'paper';
    }
}

compareChoice = (userChoice, computerChoice) => {
    if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
        console.log('Draw')
    } else if (userChoice === 'paper') {
        if (computerChoice == 'scissors') {
            console.log ('You lose, try again!')
        } else {
            console.log('You win!')
        }
    } else if (userChoice === 'rock') {
        if(computerChoice === 'paper') {
            console.log('You lose! Try again!')
        } else {
            console.log('You win!')
        }
    } else if (userChoice === 'scissors') {
        if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
            console.log('You Lose! Try again!')
        } else {
            console.log('You win!')
        }
    }
}

game = () => {
    let userChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors!');
    console.log('Your choice was ' + userChoice);
    compareChoice(userChoice, computerChoice());
}

game();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the user choice and the computer choice into  compareChoice.

```
    function game() {
        let userChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors!');
        console.log('Your choice was ' + userChoice);
        compareChoice(userChoice, computerChoice());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your game function, you are calling `compareChoice()` with no parameters. I'm not sure how the statement is even working but the only explanation seems like the parameters are both being assigned `null`. Hence the "Draw" response.

Try this instead

```
function game() {
    let userChoice = prompt('Choose rock, paper, or scissors!');
    console.log('Your choice was ' + userChoice);
    compareChoice(userChoice, computerChoice());
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Silly mistake Confused declaring and calling a function!